# Store a state in a parent component without causing re-rendering of the parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-state-management

Consider the following dummy code:

```
<Parent>
    <Form>
        <ItemEditor onItemsAdded={setItemStateOnParent} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={() => saveItems()}>Save items</button>
     </Form>
</Parent>
```

So I use a component `ItemEditor` inside a Form in a `Parent` component. When the `setItemStateOnParent` callback is called, it changes some state in the `Parent` which leads to re-rendering of the `Parent`. I don't need or want this re-rendering though - all necessary rendering is done by the `ItemEditor`. So, is there some kind of state / kind of hook that can store values across `Parent` re-renders without itself causing the `Parent` to re-render?

Comment: Not  sure but `React.memo` can be the [thing](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) you are looking for

Comment: Note that I want to prevent the rendering of the `Parent`. As soon as I change the state in the parent, the parent re-renders. `React.memo`won't change this: " If your function component wrapped in React.memo has a useState or useContext Hook in its implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change." (quoted from the documentation you linked)

Comment: A `ref` is a mutable store of value which can be changed without causing renders - it's the escape hatch from the render cycle essentially. This is not a good use case for it though. If you don't want `Parent` to rerender then don't keep the state there, move it down to `Form`. Or if this is not possible then create some sub-component which comprises all of `Form`, `ItemEditor` and `button` to isolate the state change.

Comment: @lawrence-witt If I would create a sub-component and store the state there, how would I later access this state from the outside when submitting the form in the `Parent`?

Comment: The idea would be to encapsulate everything in the new component so that that is not necessary. If that is not possible then you have to keep everything in `Parent` and accept that it will rerender. As @SinanYaman suggested, `memo` will allow you to isolate child components from the rerender if performance is a concern. As a side note, the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API or a comprehensive state-management solution like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) will go a long way to resolving issues like these.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Does "Redux will go a long way to resolving issues like these" mean that state-management solutions won't have these issues? (sorry, I am not sure what "go a long way" means from an english language point of view; not a native speaker)

Comment: This is getting a bit dense for comments now but yes, you don't have to juggle and comparmentalise state in the same way with Redux because it all lives separately from the components. Components only subscribe to the bits of state they actually need to function, and submit actions to the store which update the state and perform side effects like API requests without needing to know about the data up front.

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thank you very much for your input. Being new to React and interested in learning more about it and state management, I am glad I now found a practical example / reason when to use it and you explained it very well. Last comment ;-) You should post your information as answer, would make up a great reference. Otherwise it is still here as comments :-)